# LDAP passwort algorithm in R

Tags: r, ldap, openldap, sha

I am trying to encode Passwords for an LDAP-server-file (`.LDIF`) therefore I am trying to re-engineer a password in order to find the correct algorithm. I am working with `R`:

So here's the password I'm trying to replicate:

```
userPassword:: e1NIQX1XNnBoNU1tNVB6OEdnaVVMYlBnekczN21qOWc9
```

I know this password is "**password**" so here's my next step:

```
rawToChar(base64decode('e1NIQX1XNnBoNU1tNVB6OEdnaVVMYlBnekczN21qOWc9'))
```

this yields:

```
{SHA}W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=
```

(I know this step was not necessary but I wanted to get a grasp of what was base64-encoded)

From [my understanding](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html) this is an SHA-1 algorithm without SALT. So my next goal is to reproduce this in R by:

```
library(base64enc)
library(digest)

sha <- digest("password", "sha1", serialize = FALSE)
sha <- paste0("{SHA}", sha)
sha <- base64encode(charToRaw(sha))
sha
[1] "e1NIQX01YmFhNjFlNGM5YjkzZjNmMDY4MjI1MGI2Y2Y4MzMxYjdlZTY4ZmQ4"
```

However this not similar to the password in the `LDIF`-File I was provided with. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can recreate using `base64encode(charToRaw(paste0("{SHA}", base64encode(digest("password", algo = "sha1", raw = TRUE, serialize = FALSE)))))`.

Comment: great, thank you; would you like to share it as an answer so i would accept it and you get the credit :)